# How to store dynamically generated page as static page in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm talking about ASP.net 4.0 MVC3 database driven application. I want to know how to store dynamically generated page as static page in html? My purpose is to optimize performance of the application by avoiding database calls on each request, and serving content from static  html page when it exists else it will load from db and save html to serve next request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are after output caching refer to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx

Comment: Hi, Is there any tutorial or link that can help me understand it.

Comment: Theres not really a lot to it, apply the attribute to a controller method and set duration, a bit of experimentation goes a long way. However for a more detailed explanation try this one http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs it seems quite fleshed out.